# Unit test for asynchronous delegate call in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates

I have a function which created a delegated and starts BeginInvoke on that object, with another function being passed in to wait for EndInvoke:

```
    private static void DeploymentComponentThreadedCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        var result = (AsyncResult)ar;
        var pluginExecuteAction = (Action<int, Guid, int, EnvironmentServerComponentSet, string>)result.AsyncDelegate;
        pluginExecuteAction.EndInvoke(ar);
        //report back to WCF service that thread is finished
    }

public void DeployComponent(byte[] resource, Guid componentGuid, string deploymentType, Dictionary<string, object> args)
{
  var asyncCallback = new AsyncCallback(DeploymentComponentThreadedCallBack);
  IDeployComponent plugin = GetPluginDelegate();
  Action<byte[], Guid, string, Dictionary<string, object>> pluginExecuteAction = plugin.DeployComponent;
  IAsyncResult ar = pluginExecuteAction.BeginInvoke(resource, componentGuid, deploymentType, args, asyncCallback, null);
}
```

I'd like to unit test this, but when I do so, DeploymentComponentThreadedCallBack never gets hit, and obviously neither does the EndInvoke call. I presume this is happening because the test passes before the asynchronous thread ends, so the thread stops executing before EndInvoke, but is there a way I can stop this happening so I can see that EndInvoke gets hit?

Cheers,
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your basic problem is that you're not exposing anything on the `DeployComponent` method that would let you track the asynchronous operation that you're starting there. If you returned the `IAsyncResult` from there you could call `ar.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne()` to wait until it completed.

Comment: Sadly this is sample code - in reality DeployComponent does a lot more stuff besides and it already has a bool return type. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Well you'll have to solve that problem somehow. If you want to wait for an operation to complete you have to expose something for the caller to wait on. Under normal circumstances you continue on and don't wait for completion, but in your test you wait for it to complete. You could actually just change DeployComponent to follow the APM and report completion when all the stuff it kicks off completes. It might need a bit of refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember the [AsyncResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.messaging.asyncresult.aspx) has a flag (*IsCompleted*) that tells you whether the operation is going on. Wait on it (e.g. primitively with a while loop), and then do your assertions

Comment: There is such a flag, but how do I get at it in the calling object? i.e. If the DeployComponent method is on a a Foo object, and in my test I call Foo.DeployComponent(byteStream, new Guid(), "cmd", null); where do I get the AsyncResult to see if it's finished?

Comment: I can't see from where you're coming. You're passing the Asyncresult into the first method, so you could wait on it before passing into it.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. That's not going to work, as under normal circumstances I don't want to wait on it - only for this test. Otherwise there wouldn't be much point in doing it asynchronously.

Comment: Matt, what's missing is your test - it can't be seen where you're coming from. If you don't give yourself access to the AsyncHandle, you're probably out of luck

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to make an injection point to turn asynchrounous calls into blocking calls. For example:

```
 public class MethodInvoker
 {
     public virtual void Invoke(Action begin, Action<IAsyncResult> end)
     {
          begin.BeginInvoke(end, null);
     }
 }
```

With a unit testing version like so:

```
 public class SynchronousInvoker : MethodInvoker
 {
     public override void Invoke(Action begin, Action<IAsyncResult> end)
     {
         begin();
         end();
     }
 }
```

Then you would write code like so:

```
 _myMethodInvoker.Invoke(pluginExecuteAction, asyncCallback);
```

Which in the context of your normal functionality, is asynchronous. In your unit tests, you simply inject the SynchronousInvoker in it's place and it becomes a blocking call.

Comment: This looks like a good approach, but I can't tweak it to make it work. BeginInvoke requires a parameter of type AsyncResult, not Action<IAsyncResult> and without the Action you can't call end() on it.